# using jquery with html5 video

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I have a site that does live streaming. I have some code that can play on the iPad successfully:

```
window.location = 'http://<?php echo DEVSTREAMWEB; ?>/<?php echo $session_id;?>/'+camerahash+'/playlist.m3u8';
```

Where `DEVSTREAMWEB` is a url: `mysite.com:1935/web/_definst_` and session_id is well you guessed it, the session id. Camerahash is a built in hash number to for a specific camera that you can stream.

This opens up a new tab on the iPad and works great. However I wanted to change this to play in a div. And if someone wanted to go full screen they would just hit the full screen option to play the html5 video:

```
var theUrl = 'http://<?php echo DEVSTREAMWEB; ?>/<?php echo $session_id;?>'+camerahash+'/playlist.m3u8';
if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
    var mydiv = $("#player");
    var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+theUrl+"' width='320' height='240' controls></video>");
    mydiv.append(myvideo);
} else {
    $('#myfileplayer').attr("src",theUrl); 
}

var video = document.getElementById('myfileplayer');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
    video.play();
},false);
```

I get an error: `"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://mysite.com:1935/web/_definst_/kgbh744hkbmguc95cbts8m02949e6212905e7e58998c03ba03a36d8e08cf1032ab/playlist.m3u8"`

This is the right url. I'm wondering if my quotes are correct with `theUrl`? Any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. Forgot the slash.

```
var theUrl = 'http://<?php echo DEVSTREAMWEB; ?>/<?php echo $session_id;?>/'+camerahash+'/playlist.m3u8';
```